# resulting multiple columns from single value field

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with the below columns (Table1).

```
[Date], [Status], [Time], [Category], [Count]
```

And I've written a SQL Query using, below is the query.

```
SELECT [Date]
    ,[Status]
    ,[Time]
    ,[1 time] as '1 time'
    ,[2 times] as '2 times'
    ,[3 times] as '3 times'
    ,[4 times] as '4 times'
    ,[5 times] as '5 times'
    ,[>5 times] as '>5 times'
FROM Table1
PIVOT (
    SUM([Count])
    FOR [Category] IN 
    ([1 time], [2 times], [3 times], [4 times], [5 times], [>5 times])
) as PVT
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3, 4
```

And the I did the get the result as required with the below columns.

```
[Date], [Status], [Time], [1 time], [2 times], [3 times], [4 times], [5 times], [>5 times]
```

But I need to add one more column names as `Overall` which will give the sum of all these columns.

```
[1 time], [2 times], [3 times], [4 times], [5 times], [>5 times]
```

Can someone help me with it?

Comment: Good golly...are those your real column names? Yikes.

Comment: Even for a prototype...eek. I would change the reserved words and get rid of all the spaces. That kind of stuff just makes it so hard to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT [Date]
      ,[Status]
      ,[Time]
      ,[1 time]
      ,[2 times]
      ,[3 times]
      ,[4 times]
      ,[5 times]
      ,[>5 times]
      ,[1 time] + [2 times] + [3 times] + [4 times] + [5 times] + [>5 times] AS Overall
FROM (SELECT [Date]
            ,[Status]
            ,[Time]
            ,[1 time] as '1 time'
            ,[2 times] as '2 times'
            ,[3 times] as '3 times'
            ,[4 times] as '4 times'
            ,[5 times] as '5 times'
            ,[>5 times] as '>5 times'
     FROM Table1
     PIVOT (SUM([Count]) FOR [Category] IN ([1 time], [2 times], [3 times], [4 times], [5 times], [>5 times])) as PVT) AS T
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3, 4
```

Comment: Overall is NULL when I ran it getting results only for the rows where I have data for all the columns. Any suggestions?

Comment: What about [1 time] and the others?

Comment: Found a solution with COALESCE. How can I replace the NULL values with 0 at once in the PIVOT?

Comment: You gotta do it for each field my friend.